# How to configure the Total Subscription module?

Tags: 7, notifications

I'm taking a look at the Total Subscription module and have done the basic installation and configuration. But it's not evident how to get it to show up on any given node/page. I've been working from its documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/2170825.

Any other suggestions about how to configure it?

Comment: To those who voted to close it as unclear, my apologies. I was being as specific as I could, and included the link to the documentation to show I'd made an effort to read it, but was at a point where I didn't know what I didn't know, so was looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) module has indeed some challenges related to finding out how to get it configured as it should be. Apart from its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2170825) (which you seem to have found already), the best I have found to far is a [video tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jL41iZfxmpM) (without sound though ...) that takes you through various admin screens. E.g. to show you some of the blocks related to this module.

Apart from that, to understand what this module is about, I find its [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/total_subscription/tree/README.txt) a bit helpful, as well as the module's [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription). Here is a quote from it:

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks...I'd consulted many of these resources, but hadn't been able to make much headway at the time I posted the question. Glad to see confirmation it might have worked for Anonymous. Had to shelve the effort for now, but may return to it eventually.